# SSRS 2008 How to automate sending of reports depending on parameter in a DB table

Tags: reporting-services

I need to send aa report on a regular basis. Depending on the wanted parameters, I should configure manually 260 subscritions.
I'm guessing there is a way to automate this, I can't see exactly what to use...

Actually all my parameters are stored in a db table, with column name corresponding to my report parameter.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a 'data driven subscription' [Data Driven Subscriptions SSRS Standard Edition 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875827/data-driven-subscriptions-ssrs-standard-edition-2008)