# SSRS Split Report By User

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We use SSRS to distribute sensitive information to employees (Commissions, Pay checks etc)

What is the best way to split the report by user without requiring a separate schedule per user?

These are automated to send out, so no user accessing the files from the report server, they only see the email that is sent out.

Example Below -

Entire Report

[image: EntireReport]

So if Pilar is in the list of recipients that will receive this mail, he should only see the below info.

[image: Split For User Pilar]

Comment: Guess the email addresses are already stored in a table. Make that a parameter in the report and generate individual reports for individual email addresses

Comment: Data driven subscription if you have Enterprise: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms169673.aspx else try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875827/data-driven-subscriptions-ssrs-standard-edition-2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server Reporting Services data-driven subscription](http://www.kodyaz.com/reporting-services/create-data-driven-subscription-in-sql-server.aspx) as a solution.

If you check the referred Reporting Services example, you take a list of receivers of the report with email address for sending the report via email.
You can add this email address or userid as an import parameter to SQL stored procedure which serves the data.
You can select NULL values for specific users in the data query.

This method enables SQL developers to create reports tailored for each receiver.